# question rate-limit/bans? What's the difference?

Tags: discussion

https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking-rate-limited

https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans

I have a question regarding those 2 help pages and the features they describe.

Do both show the same message? It sounds like it's the exact same feature. Atleast from the implications made in the first link. The main question is wheater the shown message is the same as the first link does not provide screenshots from the message itself.

Answer (score 5):

They aren't the same feature. Rate limiting is the *precursor* to a Q-Ban.

The rate limit message will ask you to wait X amount of days before asking again, a ban will say "We are no longer accepting questions from this account".

Do take care to avoid the Q-Ban. Its very hard to get out of. If you are getting rate limited, its a warning. Fix your posts before its too late!

Comment: It's sadly to late. Eventhough I have only 11 questions, I made the mistake to delete the 3-4 bad ones I started with. This must have skipped me from the rate limit right into the Q-Ban.

Comment: @LinuxNoob1337 Thats awfully fast for a Q-Ban. Were they *really* bad? Are you sure you are getting the "Not accepting questions" message? In any case, you need to fix your *existing* posts to get out of it. Good answers can also help.

Comment: @LinuxNoob1337 - I see that on December 15, as you were approaching the question ban, you were indeed warned that you would be limited from asking if you continued at the rate you were. That's an example of the warning system in action, at which point you were rate-limited but continued to post.

Comment: In addition to the above, I should mention that there are other rate limits for question asking than just those applied by the lead-up to the question ban: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/135615 (a maximum of 6 questions per day and a maximum of 50 questions per 30 days).

Comment: @Bard Larson, well, I think that exactly was what triggered me to delete my bad questions I think, I though this would remove "pollution" and allow me to ask new questions with better content. Especially as the old ones had a lot of comments flaming in it, thus seemed unsalvageable.